# "I give this copyright"; Is it right?

Tags: word-choice

This thesis is the product of my own research. Hereby **I give** my copyright to University X.

Is that right?

Comment: It's helpful to explain what you're trying to say when you're asking if something is correct. In English, there are many ways something can be grammatically correct and not mean what you are trying to say. If you explain what you hope the sentence will mean, it makes it easier for us to give you good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to say.

If you want the university to be allowed to do whatever they want with your work, but you still want the work to belong to you, you'd say

> I hearby waive all copyright for the University's use of this work

If you want to give your copyright to the university, so you no longer own the work and the university can sue people who break the terms of their copyright, you would say

> I hearby transfer all copyright and ownership of this work to the University.

Answer (score 0):

In reading anything about copyright and how it works, I've always seen the term "assigned" or "transferred" be used.